# param is missing or the value is empty - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Heres the full error. param is missing or the value is empty: module_list
It's throwing up the error near the bottom under def module_list_params where module_list is required. I've looked at several other solutions to the problem but they do not help me. Heres my code.

```
  class ModuleListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_module_list, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_student, only: [:new, :create]

  # GET /module_lists
  # GET /module_lists.json
  def index
    @module_lists = ModuleList.all
  end

  # GET /module_lists/1
  # GET /module_lists/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /module_lists/new
  def new
    @module_list = @student.module_lists.new
  end

  # GET /module_lists/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /module_lists
  # POST /module_lists.json
  def create
    @module_list = @student.module_lists.new(module_list_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @module_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @module_list, notice: 'Module successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @module_list }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @module_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /module_lists/1
  # PATCH/PUT /module_lists/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @module_list.update(module_list_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @module_list, notice: 'Module list was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @module_list }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @module_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /module_lists/1
  # DELETE /module_lists/1.json
  def destroy
    @module_list.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to module_lists_url, notice: 'Module list was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_module_list
      @module_list = ModuleList.find(params[:id])
    end

    def module_list_params
      params.require(:module_list).permit(:student_id, :title, :description,     :credit_value)
    end

    def set_student
      @student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id]) ||
      Student.find(module_list_params[:student_id])
    end
end
```

Comment: When are you getting this error? You're requiring `module_list` to be present in the parameters, is it?

Comment: make sure you have input's name 'module_list' in your form

Comment: It's when I press new module list to create one

Comment: Do you use byebug or some debugging gem? If so, put a breakpoint in that method and show us what params is

Comment: sorry no i dont, ill install it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [param is missing or the value is empty: module\_list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215643/param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty-module-list)

Comment: can you show your params hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is quite simple - [*strong params*](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) requires `module_list` to be assigned in the params, as follows:

```
params: {
   module_list: {
     student_id:   "w",
     title:        "x",
     description:  "y",
     credit_value: "z"
   }
}
```

Whenever you call `params.require(:module_list)`, it basically needs the params to be structured as above. If they're *not* structured like that, you'll receive the error that the controller requires the params, which is what you have.

This problem can be caused by several issues, but the main is that you're not setting the `form_for` correctly. You'd have to set it as follows:

```
#app/controllers/modules_list_controller.rb
class ModulesListController < ApplicationController
   def new
     @module_list = ModuleList.new
   end
   def create
     @module_list = ModuleList.new module_list_params
     @module_list.save
   end
```

end

This would be accompanied with the following `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for @module_list do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field ... %>
<% end %>
```

---

Since you seem to be using [`nested routes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), I would suggest the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :students do
   resources :module_lists, only: [:new, :create]
end

#app/controllers/modules_lists_controller.rb
class ModuleListsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @module_list = @student.module_lists.new
   end
end

#app/views/module_lists/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [@student, @module_list] do |f| %>
   <%= ... %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Update**

The problem is here:

```
def set_student
   @student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id]) ||
      Student.find(module_list_params[:student_id])
end
```

Because you're trying to invoke `module_list_params`, it is literally thinking it has to have accepted a params hash, which isn't the case with the `new` action.

In this instance (IE if you're using a nested resource all the time), you'll just be able to get away with referencing `params[:student_id]`:

```
def set_student
   @student = Student.find params[:student_id]
end
```

--

On further inspection, there is another issue.

You're calling `set_student` for the `new` action. Whilst this should work fine *if* you had nested resources (as I recommended), it will cause a problem if not.

As such, you need to do the following:

```
#app/controllers/modules_list_controller.rb
class ModuleListController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_student, only: :create #-> new doesn't have a student
```

This will allow you to use the following in your `new` action:

```
#app/views/module_lists/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @module_list do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :student_id, Student.all, :id, :name %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already had the form set like how you suggested and changed def new and def create like you said but got the same error

Comment: Can you post your params hash?

Comment: sorry I don't fully understand what you mean by params hash (new to this)

Comment: When you send the request to your server, it will send the parameters in a hash (this is what `params.require` looks up). You can see this in your console when you send the request - I would like to see what is sent when the error is created

Comment: The console just displays the same error as the title, and says:

Comment: ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: module_list):
  app/controllers/module_lists_controller.rb:78:in `module_list_params'
  app/controllers/module_lists_controller.rb:73:in `set_student'

Comment: Yes, but before the error, it will show the request which caused it. Can you post the request? It will have parameters in it http://imgur.com/U6Ubtlu

Comment: Above the error it only says one other thing which is: Student Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Completed 400 Bad Request

Comment: Above that? There *has* to be a place where the parameters are posted

Comment: I'm afraid there's not :/ I'm only pressing new_module_list to take me to the form, not actually filling one out

Comment: So it's coming back when you hit the `new` view?

Comment: Yeah, when I press new on the view

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried that and now I get: "Couldn't find Student with 'id'".

Comment: I made a small mistake in my update (`studend_it`) - did you correct it? If not, you should see the update

Comment: Yeah, it threw up the error Couldn't find Student with 'id'

Comment: Do you have nested routes or not?

Comment: That's probably the problem. Let me make another update, sorry about all the messing around

Comment: Updated - stop `set_student` from invoking for `:new`

Comment: Thanks for the update, I followed what you said and made my resources nested, however now that they are nested I get a new error:

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"module_lists"} missing required keys: [:student_id]. I'm definitely using the correct route after using rake routes, I'm guessing it has something to do with the missing require keys

Comment: Don't nest the resources - do what the update says without nesting them

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I tried what you said and now I get: undefined method `module_lists' for nil:NilClass under 'def new'

Comment: change the def new to `@module_list = ModuleList.new`

Comment: That worked! However when I try to press the 'save' button I get: undefined method `take' for, and it points at the line inside 'set_student'.

Comment: ok remove the `before_action` method altogether and it should work for you