# param is missing or the value is empty: module_list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to enter a list of new modules and when I press 'new module list' which should take me to the form to fill out it throws up the error from the title. The application trace points at the bottom, the code inside 'def module_list_params' and also just above it where 'def set_student' is. I have no idea why it's doing it. I'm using ruby on rails.

```
class ModuleListsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_module_list, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :set_student, only: [:new, :create]

  # GET /module_lists
  # GET /module_lists.json
  def index
    @module_lists = ModuleList.all
  end

  # GET /module_lists/1
  # GET /module_lists/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /module_lists/new
  def new
    @module_list = @student.module_lists.new
  end

  # GET /module_lists/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /module_lists
  # POST /module_lists.json
  def create
    @module_list = @student.module_lists.new(module_list_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @module_list.save
        format.html { redirect_to @module_list, notice: 'Module successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @module_list }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @module_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /module_lists/1
  # PATCH/PUT /module_lists/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @module_list.update(module_list_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @module_list, notice: 'Module list was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @module_list }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @module_list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /module_lists/1
  # DELETE /module_lists/1.json
  def destroy
    @module_list.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to module_lists_url, notice: 'Module list was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_module_list
      @module_list = ModuleList.find(params[:id])
    end

    def module_list_params
      params.require(:module_list).permit(:student_id, :title, :description,     :credit_value)
    end

    def set_student
      @student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id]) ||
      Student.find(module_list_params[:student_id])
    end
end
```

Rake routes screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is the line `before_action :set_student, only: [:new, :create]`. `set_student` is being run when you go to the page with the form, but since there is no `student_id` included in the URL, it can't find anything to set it to.

To create a dependent object, there are two main ways: you can either have a form page tied to a specific parent object already, ie `/students/4/module_lists/new`, in which case submitting the form will create a module list tied to the student with an ID of 4. The other way is to have a general form not tied to any specific parent object, with some way of selecting a parent inside the form, eg a select or something. In that case the url would just be something like `/module_lists/new`.

If you want to go the first route, you'll want to nest the `resources :module_lists` inside of `students`. Check out the [docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) for how to do that, but it would basically look like

```
resources :students do
  resources :module_list
end
```

And then in the `link_to` you click to go to that page, you'll need to pass in the `student_id`:

```
link_to 'Create Module List', new_student_module_list_path(@student)
```

For the second option, you can just remove `:new` from the before_action, change the `new` method to

```
def new
  @module_list = ModuleList.new
end
```

And then add a way of picking which student to tie it to to the form.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it and when trying the same thing again I get the error "undefined method `module_lists' for nil:NilClass" which points at the line in 'def new'

Comment: Mmmm that makes sense, since now `@student` in the `new` method will be nil >< What does the URL for the form look like? is `:student_id` included in it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by URL for the form, sort of new to this but the fields in my form doesn't include student_id if that's what you meant

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was what url would you use to get to this form? It's probably something like `/student/:student_id/module-list/new`, or `/module-list/new`

Comment: Ah gotcha, it is /module_lists/new

Comment: Ok cool, that explains it! I'll update my answer in a sec to try, let me know if it still doesn't help

Comment: I tried applying your updated answer but i get "No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"module_lists", :student_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:student_id]"

Comment: Which option did you try? Can you add the output of running `rake routes` to your question?

Comment: Option one, yeah but I changed the code back to the original in the post from what you suggested since it didn't work